# How to add a column to a table using functions or expressions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to add another column to my table by using functions or expressions and I get an error

> Incorrect syntax near '='

The function is calculating based on two columns from the `tblGrades` table.

Is there a way to add a column using expressions or functions?

```
ALTER TABLE tblGrades
    ADD AvgScores dec

SET AvgScores = (SELECT CONVERT(DOUBLE PRECISION, ROUND((SUM(WrittenExam) + SUM(CodingExam)) * 1.0 / (COUNT(WrittenExam) + COUNT(CodingExam)), 1)) AS AvgScore
                 FROM tblGrades)
```

Comment: Are you referring to a computed / calculated column?

Comment: It calculated two columns in the tblGrades table by average.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation for how to use an update statement? It looks like you are just guessing at SQL syntax there are lots of references out there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a computed column for your purpose:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tblGrades ADD AvgScores AS (convert(DOUBLE PRECISION, Round((sum(WrittenExam) + sum(CodingExam)) * 1.0 / (count(WrittenExam) + count(CodingExam)), 1))) PERSISTED;
```

As SQL Server doesn't like aggregation functions in a computed column, we have to use an UPDATE.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tblGrades ADD AvgScores dec    
GO

UPDATE tblGrades 
SET tblGrades.AvgScores = t1.avg_scores
FROM tblGrades t
CROSS JOIN  (
    SELECT CONVERT(DOUBLE PRECISION, Round((sum(WrittenExam) + sum(CodingExam)) * 1.0 / (count(WrittenExam) + count(CodingExam)), 1)) avg_scores
    FROM tblGrades
) t1
```

But you need also have a trigger that calculates every time a new exam was added.

Comment: The problem with this is that it gives this error: "An aggregate may not appear in a computed column expression or check constraint."

Comment: @cube901 yes, ms sql server throws an error, so a update statements must be performed every time you add an exam see the changed answer

Comment: @DaleK  sql server 2019 doesn't mind and throws no error, i have tested it a priori